# how to get ? pub/static/frontend/Magento/luma/en_US/Namespace_Module/images/image.png

Tags: magento2.2

> How to get this path ?
>   "pub/static/frontend/Magento/luma/en_US/Namespace_Module/images/image.png"

Answer (score 0):

```
echo $block->getViewFileUrl('Vendor_Module::images/yourImage.jpg');
```